# Раскрывающийся список

Tags: база-данных, javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">

<!--
var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all?1:0
var head="display:''"
var folder=''
function expandit(curobj){
folder=ns6?curobj.nextSibling.nextSibling.style:document.all[curobj.sourceIndex+1].style
if (folder.display=="none")
folder.display=""
else
folder.display="none"
}
//-->
</script>
<p style="cursor:pointer" onClick="expandit(this)">Россия</p>
<span style="display:none" style=&{head};>
Москва<br>
Волгоград<br>
Тверь<br>
</span>
<p style="cursor:pointer" onClick="expandit(this)">Италия</p>
<span style="display:none" style=&{head};>
Милан<br>
Турин
</span>
```

В моем варианте города надо вписывать самому, возможен ли вариант, при котором города будут заполнятся автоматическими из базы данных?

Comment: `language="JavaScript1.2"` - ад. Уберите и не пишите так никогда.

Comment: @LOKIMO, учитывая то, что Вы не уточнили ни структуру, ни тип БД, ни даже серверный язык, то ответ на Ваш вопрос ограничивается фразой "да, возможен".

Comment: язык php, бд mysql, может есть готовые скрипты  js скрипт для этого?